# Problems with authorizations for Google Apps APIs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to synchronize contacts from local adress books to Domain Shared Contacts using a simple Google Apps Script. Therefore I wrote a small script, which reads my contacts, let me select the contact I want to copy to the DSC and then creates the new User using the Admin SDK.

Everything works, except the creation of the user in the Directory. This is what I am doing:

```
for (c in contactIDs){
  var contact = ContactsApp.getContact(contactIDs[c]);
  var user = {
    primaryEmail: contact.getPrimaryEmail(),
    name: {
      givenName: contact.getGivenName(),
      familyName: contact.getFamilyName()
    },
    domain: 'xyz.com',
    // Generate a random password string.
    password: Math.random().toString(36)
  };
  user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
}
```

I am admin in the domain, I have all rights, I can imagine, but I always get this error message:

Error encountered: Not Authorized to access this resource/api

What am i missing? Is there something with the OAuth settings, I don't understand? I am confused...

Thanks and best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Have you enabled the service in the admin console?  Have you tried the user creation from within the doc test page?

Comment: Yes, the service is enabled. Not sure, if I understand what you mean with "doc test page". Could you explain this? Thanks, Sebastian